# How to POST blob as a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form, which contents two inputs one hidden with name="action" and second with name="avatar" type="file".
After user choose the file in the avatar input the image converts to blob.
How can I post the blob like it was loaded as a file and after submited?

Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="avatarform">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
    <input id="coolButton" name="avatar" type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" placeholder="">
</form>
```

I have try:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('action', 'save');
fd.append('avatar', file.name);
fd.append('data', blob);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
});
```

php controller:

```
    if ($_FILES['avatar']['name']) {
        if ($profile->avatar==1) {
            unlink('/images/avatars/'.$profile->avatar);
            $profile->avatar=0;
        }
        $filename="avatar_".$user_id.'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['avatar']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/images/avatars/".$filename);
        $profile->avatar=$filename;
    }
```

But php controller does not save it. If I use form without script wich converts image to blob - it works good and save the file.

Comment: please provide some more code

Comment: file.name = name of loaded file;
blob = data:image/png;base64,..............[binarycode];

Only this part of code makes POST action, other code updates the blob.
I just want to get the method to submit the form with updated image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated script

```
fd.append('blob', blob.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
fd.append('ext', "jpg") // send ext of uploaded file
```

And php controller

```
    if ($_POST['blob']) {
        if ($profile->avatar==1) {
            unlink('/images/avatars/'.$profile->avatar);
            $profile->avatar=0;
        }
        $file = base64_decode($_POST['blob']);
        $filename="avatar_".$user_id.'.'.$_POST['ext'];
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/images/avatars/".$filename, $file);
        $profile->avatar=$filename;
    }
```

Comment: Hi mike, can I get you to make a example of the full code? can't get it to work and im not sure what is wrong