# Upload a blob file created using javascript to a php server

Tags: javascript, php, html

Javascript:

```js
let myFile = new Blob(["A file"], { type: "text/plain"});

fetch("server_location.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: myFile,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  })
  .then((res) => { return res.text(); }
  .then((text) => { console.log(text) };
```

Php:

```php
<?php
var_dump($_FILES)
```

Required
`Should show the file in the file array`
Output
`array (0)`

Please give me a solution so that I can upload custom text blob file created in javascript to my php server.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am new to fetch api and php so i have no idea

Comment: Did you try to search for similar problems? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630690/how-to-post-blob-as-a-file-using-javascript helps

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101609/retrieve-uploaded-blob-with-php

Comment: Read the manual: [Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob

Comment: But here the file is created manually

Comment: Either use `multipart/form-data` or don't use `$_FILES`. These are your two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_FILES` is populated when you upload a request formatted as Multipart Form Data and labeled with the current content-type.

You are uploading a blob labelled as plain text, and stringifed (probably to `[object Object]`).

---

To send a multipart request, use a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
const myFile = new Blob(["A file"], { type: "text/plain"});
const data = new FormData();
data.append("myFile", myFile, "filename.txt");
fetch("server_location.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
})
```

---

To send plain text and read it:

- Don't use a blob
- Do read from STDIN

```js
fetch("server_location.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: "a plain text string",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }
})
```

and

```php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a blob or along with fetch, and he isn't stringifing anything, it may just be a dummy blob, demonstration us currently how he uploads a file with fetch. i do think `file_get_contents` would be the right answer.

Answer (score -4):

If you are sending a file then "Content-Type" shouldn't be "text/plain".

Set Content-Type to "multipart/form-data".

```
{
    "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

Comment: The body **isn't** multipart/form-data so that won't work. Even if it was, the content-type for `multipart/form-data` has a **mandatory** `boundary` parameter that you omitted.